# Getting Cannot find mercurial executable at path 'hg'

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, agent

I am using VCS checkout mode to agent side and also have defined the teamcity.hg.agent.path = c:\program files\mercurial\hg.exe in agent.properties file. Still VCS is not picking up this setting and giving me the following error:-

```
Test connection failed in Dev :: Stocks :: Build and Package. Cannot find mercurial executable at path 'hg'
```

Also have defined the path in windows environment variables. Mercurial is not installed on server machine. I have read in documentation that if you are using a agent side checkout then not required. Please guide what I am missing here.
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Mode), if you're using *server* side checkout, then you don't need to install mercurial on your *agent*.

But when you set up version control as a VCS root, you do need the TeamCity server to be able to talk to the mercurial server so it can do things like detect changes. The JetBrains documentation [specifically says](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Mercurial) that if you're using a Mercurial VCS root:

> Mercurial should be installed in the server machine, and, if
>   agent-side checkout is used, on the agents.

Comment: Thanks! This was the same issue for Upsource.